# How to compare struct with pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to compare a field of a struct that is holding a pointer of char with a pointer of char, but the comparison is not working.

```
typedef struct node{
    char * word;
    struct node * next;
    int occurrence;

}No;
```

---

```
           aux = list;
           while(aux != NULL){
            if(aux->word == token)
            {
                new_node->occurrence = new_node->occurrence+1;
                exist = 0;
            }
            aux = aux->next;
        }
```

Comment: We'll need a little bit more code than that. What is `list`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(aux->word == token)`

Well you are comparing addresses and in the case they are equal (which is highly unlikely) it will enter the block.

Correct way to do is to check the contents. `strcmp()` is there to help you with that.

```
strcmp(aux->word, token) == 0
```

Compares the content pointed by them. That is appropriate here.

Comment: Well, it is posible that the adresses are the same. But indeed, he probably wants to know if the strings are the same.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie.: Not possible is too strong...But yes the OP wants to compare strings simply.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
if (aux->word == token) {
}
```

You need to write:

```
if (strcmp(aux->word, token) == 0) {
// your code here
}
```

> man strcmp

Answer (score 0):

The == operator will not work with strings. The standard function strcmp() should be used. The function will return 0 if the strings are equal.